# What kind of 6x1 connector is this?

Tags: identification, connector

I'm trying to build a diy pedal adapter for my digital piano. The piano has a 6x1 2.54mm pitch female socket header. It has a serrated side, and a little notch on the other side to secure the male connector.

[image: Pedal female connector]

Male connector:

[image: Pedal male connector]

A schematic view of the connectors:

[image: Schematic connector view]

What is the name of this particular pin header connector?

Comment: You should take it out and do a better photo.

Comment: I know. Unfortunately I don't have access to the male header. These pictures are everything I could find online.

Comment: replace the connector with a DB9 connector ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=db9+connector&iax=images&ia=images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [JST SM connector](https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/detail_e.php?series=238). I ordered samples of this connector, tested and confirmed this is the one.